# How can I Mount multiple iso?

Tags: 12.04, mount, iso

I have multiple iso files, actually two. I use Furius ISO Mount. Can I mount multiple iso files in a single image with this tool or another under Ubuntu 12.04? And how can I do it?

Edit: 
**I need to system see the full dvd.** *This is the main task. I hope this clarification makes clear the meaning of my question.*

Comment: "multiple iso files in a single image"? Do you want to mount iso which are within another iso file?

Comment: Do you want to mount 2 ISO files to the same directory?

Comment: @CoalaWeb, yes I think I need to do just that.

Comment: What are you trying to do? do you need to combine the ISO data?

Comment: Or, maybe I should to mount iso which are within another iso file, right as A.S. told. If I try to install app from first mounted image it still ask for dvd. I do not know what the approach is better.

Comment: Can you not mount them both with Furious and during the installation process direct it to the second ISO.

Comment: This is application, but I'll try.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is still somewhat ambiguous and unclear to me *(Blaming myself)*. I'm answering this considering each case:

#### Case 1: Mount iso which is within another iso file

If you are asking whether you can  mount an iso file which is within another iso file, I would say, ***Yes, You can mount an iso file which is itself in another iso file***

For example, Let us assume we have an iso file named `file1.iso` in our home directory and there is another iso file inside it named `inside.iso`. One way to mount both iso file is ---

1. Create two folder in your home. Each for each iso file.

   ```
    mkdir ~/iso1 ~/isoInside
   ```
2. Mount the first iso file in the ~/iso1 directory

   ```
    sudo mount ~/file1.iso ~/iso1 -o loop
   ```
3. Then mount the second iso file inside this iso to "~/isoInside" directory

   ```
    sudo mount ~/iso1/inside.iso ~/isoInside -o loop
   ```

Now you have the first iso file mounted in "~/iso1" folder and the second one in "~/isoInside" folder

#### Case 2: Mount two iso file in a single directory.

If you are asking whether you can mount an iso file to a folder and then mount another iso file in the same previous folder, I would, ***Yes, you can do that also. But You cannot access the content of first mounted iso file***.

That is, if you mount an iso file `iso1.iso` in a folder, say `/mnt` and then mount another iso file `iso2.iso` in the same folder `/mnt`, you will only see and access the content of `iso2.iso` file in `/mnt`. You cannot access the contents of `iso1.iso` file in `/mnt` folder until you unmount the second iso file, i.e `iso2.iso` file.

**Take note that, in such cases, you cannot either unmount the first iso file. You must unmount the second one and then first one**.

*I think, you are having a problem with installation from an iso file (probably from alternate installer iso), if this is indeed the case, I suggest you to ask a question about your problem.*

Hope this answer will help.

Comment: I need to system see the full dvd. And I think it will be necessarily at each application starts (have no chance to check this state of affairs). In what the case listed above this will be possible?

Answer (score 0):

I have done the trick. I made a directory, after I mount the ISO and by order, transfer data of both mounted drives to the directory. Finally, I made one ISO from merged data.

- Thanks you people for help! *